# rotation offsets for KECCAK-$f$[800]

Tags: hash, sha-3, keccak

So let's say you're trying to do SHA3-224.

If you're on a 64-bit machine you'd presumably use KECCAK-$f$[1600]. In-so-far as I understand it'd have the following parameters:

- Rate: 448 (2*224)
- Capacity: 1152 (1600 - rate)
- Rounds: 24
- Rotation constants: described in https://keccak.team/keccak_specs_summary.html  (last table)

With a 32-bit machine you'd presumably be using KECCAK-$f$[800] with the following parameters (last table):

- Rate: 448 (2*224)
- Capacity: 352 (800 - rate)
- Rounds: 22 ($12 + 2*\log_2(800/25)$)

Assuming that that's all correct then what I'm wondering about is how the rotation constants would work.

https://keccak.team/files/Keccak-reference-3.0.pdf#page=21 gives a formula for determining the rotation constants: $(t+1)(t+2)/2$ and https://keccak.team/files/Keccak-reference-3.0.pdf#page=22 shows a table with the results of the formula. To get the rotation constants at https://keccak.team/keccak_specs_summary.html you take the lower lower six bits of each of those numbers (eg. $x \land 0x3F$ or $x \mod 64$).

For KECCAK-$f$[800] would you take the lower five bits (eg. $x \land 0x1F$ or $x \mod 32$) of each of those numbers?

A lot of the 32-bit SHA3 implementations I've seen seem to do KECCAK-$f$[1600] and just simulate 64-bit numbers with 2x 32-bit numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two assumptions are **mutually incompatible**:

> you're trying to do SHA3-224

and

> with a 32-bit machine you'd presumably be using KECCAK-f[800]

because chapter 6.1 of the SHA-3 Standard FIPS PUB 202 (the link can be found [here](https://www.nist.gov/publications/sha-3-standard-permutation-based-hash-and-extendable-output-functions?pub_id=919061)) defines

> $\text{SHA3-224}(M) = \text{Keccak}[448](M \mathbin\Vert 01, 224)$,

but chapter 2.4 of this Standard defines that

> $\text{Keccak}[c]$ is the Keccak instance with $\text{Keccak-}f[1600]$ as the underlying permutation and capacity $c$.

Regarding the question about the rotation offsets for $\text{Keccak-}f[800]$ — see chapter 3.2.2 of the SHA-3 Standard FIPS PUB 202 and note that $w=32$. For example, I have seen both the algorithm and the precomputed offsets here:

[github.com/XKCP/XKCP/.../KeccakP-800-reference.c](https://github.com/XKCP/XKCP/blob/master/lib/low/KeccakP-800/Reference/KeccakP-800-reference.c).

Comment: Chapter 3.2.2 talks about $w = 8$. Why talk about any $w$ other than $64$ if only $\text{Keccak-}f[1600]$ (with $w = 64$) is used?

Comment: @neubert: Because SHA-3 function is **derived** from Keccak, so Keccak is defined **before** SHA-3 function specifications. Chapter 3.2.2 contains **an illustration** of RHO for the case $w = 8$ in Figure 4, but Algorithm 2 is defined for all possible values of $w$. See Table 1 in chapter 3.1. But SHA-3 function specifications are given in chapter 6 of this Standard. The width of the underlying permutation of SHA-3 is 1600 bits, which corresponds to $w = 64$.